# If Magic SE opens, will all Magic questions be migrated from Board and Card Games?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering, migration

SE won't migrate questions from [Draw3Cards](http://draw3cards.com/) ... but if a proper Magic SE 2.0 opens, will questions be migrated on mass from Board & Card Games to Magic SE? They will definitely be "more on topic" there than here.

Let's not turn this question into a debate whether Magic SE should open or not, and assume for the moment that it will.

Comment: Based on the stance towards [migrating poker questions](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/685/are-there-any-plans-to-migrate-poker-questions-to-poker-stackexchange-com), I would assume no.

Comment: Closing this as the Magic SE proposal has been shuttered.

Comment: @PatLudwig Sucks that Magic SE was declined. The Magic tag is the most popular tag here, and has about as much traffic on this site as the next *four* games combined, and would benefit from having its own site. It's not fair to rob Magic of its site just to revive Board & Card Games.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**,

Beta sites are discouraged from migrating in general.  Furthermore Magic would still be on topic here.  Other SE sites overlap in some areas, we wouldn't be breaking new ground here.

Comment: Can you say why?  It seems seeding a site with the ultra-relevant could only help it?

Comment: @NealTibrewala - Magic would still be on topic here.  There is no need to migrate questions that are on topic here.  As I noted, other SE sites overlap, and coexist just fine.

Comment: Where would a person like me contribute to the discussion on a MtG SE ?

Answer (score 2):

If the Magic SE proposal manages to get into beta and further, out of beta, then there might be some room to discuss it, until then though shuffling messages between betas seems somewhat futile.

Comment: This makes the most sense, as I understand it a beta SE can fail.  Moving relevant questions from B&CG only to lose them if a beta doesn't make it to a full site would be a waste.  If the Magic SE becomes the primary source of MTG related questions then migrating would make sense.

Comment: Well... if they were migrated and then M:TG SE were to fail, they'd most likely be migrated right back.